# platform-independent time calculation

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've got a function to return a platform-dependent timestamp with high precision. Now I'd like to subtract 5 seconds from such a timestamp and am looking for the smartest way to achieve this.

This is the function:

```
def get_time():
   """ start timer """
   if sys.platform == "win32":
      return time.clock()
   else:
      return time.time()
```

Comment: Where did you get this from?

Comment: More context would also be useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use [`timeit.default_timer`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.default_timer), which does exactly that (get the most precise timer for the current platform).

To subtract 5 seconds, just subtract 5:

```
import timeit

timeit.default_timer() - 5
```

The time given is a float value representing seconds.

Comment: Not sure I'm convinced: ">>> time.time is timeit.default_timer is True"

Comment: And the docs don't guarantee accuracy either (short of a second)

Comment: @Jon: the module aliases either `time.time` or `time.clock` depending on the platform. The OP wraps them in a function instead, instead of testing for the platform once.

Comment: I had to force that out of you, but it was always going to be a +1 :)