# time.time() faster than time.clock()?

Tags: python, benchmarking

I'm writing a test in Python that iterates over large amounts of data and
executes a function with each of them, using an external library.  In each
loop, it sometimes also needs to somehow decode and mangle the data.  Now
benchmarking is not the main priority, but I want it to measure some basic
stats like the difference in the actual test and the overhead caused by the
mangling (in case it gets out of hand).

Most sources including [an SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85451/python-time-clock-vs-time-time-accuracy) seem to suggest using timeit module,
but most of them seem to talk about benchmarking simple code snippets.  Also
as the answer points out, time.clock() seems to be recommended for that.

But I haven't found a comparison between the actual *speed* of the two
calls.  So I have been experimenting with time.time and time.clock to find
out which one is faster and surprisingly time.time() seems to be the winner.

This code (borrowed from "[The Optimization anecdote](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str.html)"):

```
import time

def timing0(f, n):
    print f.__name__,
    r = range(n)
    t1 = time.clock()
    for i in r:
        f(); f(); f(); f(); f()
        f(); f(); f(); f(); f()
    t2 = time.clock()
    print t2-t1

timing0(time.clock, 1000000)
timing0(time.time, 1000000)
```

almost constantly outputs numbers like this:

```
me@here:~$ ./timing_time
clock 2.47
time 0.47
me@here:~$
```

Only difference being that time() is much more precise: when I use time() for
the measuring, I get about 11 digits after decimal dot.

But time(), even that it's less precise, it's always about 5 times faster.

So why clock() is preferred?  Does this heavily depend on the architecture
and OS?  Or am I missing something and my results are incorrect?

The above code ran on Debian Wheezy amd64 and Python 2.7.  I tried it on
Squeeze amd64 with Python 2.6 running in OpenVZ, and the results were
roughly the same.

Comment: This depends on the OS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [platform-independent time calculation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823052/platform-independent-time-calculation)

Comment: Also see http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.default_timer

Comment: You cannot compare the speed between the two calls; you'd use either one or the other, *always* and their difference in call time should not matter compared to whatever you are measuring. No point in using `time.clock` when you really should use `time.time` for your platform either.

Comment: Last but not least, both functions are proxies for the underlying C API calls, so their performance is *heavily* dependent on the OS.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Regarding the duplicate: I'm not trying to do this platform-independently, as the other question.  I'm OK with choosing what's better for my environment, as I probably already did. I'm just hoping to gain more insight before shooting myself in my four-dimensional foot.

Comment: Sure; the short answer is that there is no point in comparing the two methods. Sometimes you need a hammer, sometimes you need a screwdriver. You don't ask if one or the other is faster; you either have a nail or a screw before you and trying to use a screwdriver on the nail may work but is not the best choice.